# Searching for hardware via lspci

Tags: debian, modem, pci, mobile

I just bought Lenovo ThinkPad X201 t. I have installed Debian Jessie (testing). I was able to make working all of its hardware, but with one exception. And that is mobile broadband modem. I have checked it: it's there and correctly pluged. Mobile bradband is allowed by BIOS. When I have runned `lspci` the results was:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 06)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (rev 35)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

Well, not one looks like it (at least to me). If it is not there, does it mean it is a hardware problem? Because I'm pretty sure that it should be on PCI bus (not some internal USB or something else).

Thank you!

Comment: Try _rfkill_. Besides, it is the best hardware question i've ever seen.

Comment: I am not be sure that is on PCI exactly (try `lsusb`). Secondary try to search by modem name + notebook name for some drivers

Comment: True, I have found it on USB bus (I dont know how it had get there). Next time I muss look at whole machine.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the device is blocked by `rfkill`. If so, this is not a hardware problem. To check out, run the rfkill(1) utility programme `rfkill list`. If a mobile broadband modem is listed and shown as "blocked", then unblock it with the same programme. See manuals.

`rfkill` is a subsystem to activate and deactivate radio transceivers. When a device is blocked by `rfkill`, it is not listed in PCI probing.

Comment: rfkill programme is provided by the rfkill debian package.